# Shell script that finds specific folder recursively and set ACL

Tags: linux, shell, unix, directory

I'm very new in shell scripting and I would like to write a simple script that finds some specific folders like 01-folder and 02-folder from a defined root folder and set certain ACLs for that.

Those folders exist multiple times in very different directories.

```
for d in */ ; do

if [ -d "01-folder" ];
then 
    echo "01-folder existiert"
    # Delete ACL
    setfacl -R -b 01-folder
    # Set ACL
    setfacl -R -m group:"mydomain\mygroup":rwx 01-folder
else 
    echo "01-folder doesn't"
    
fi  
done
```

The script only finds 01-folder on the same level as the script. How do I look for 01-folder in different subfolders? I would like to have the path of the found folder in a variable.

I know it's very basic but would be very happy if soumeone can help me or even have a better solution.

Kind Regards,
Web Crawler!

Comment: UNIX is very much "divide an conquer": Use find(1) to find the files you are interested in, and then execute (maybe using xargs(1)) a command on those files (or directories). Maybe start with `find . -type d -name 01-folder -print 0 | xargs -0 ls -ld`...

Answer (score -1):

```
**find / -type d -name 01-folder -exec setfacl -R -b {} \; -exec setfacl -R -m g:yourgroup:rwx {} \;**
```